# Gradle build for 2 platforms: JavaFX and Android. How to?

Tags: java, android, gradle, javafx, cross-platform

I have an app that works on 2 platforms: Android and JavaFX.

Basically, my sources look like this:

```
java
   |
   |---android //android specific sources
   | 
   |---common  //plain java common sources
   |
   |---fx      //JavaFX specific sources
```

For the moment I'm using 2 different build files one of them `build.android.gradle` and the other `build.fx.gradle` and instantly renaming them to `build.gradle` depending on the situation. I mean it is an odd and real nightmare.

My intention is to have either 2 different `build.gradle` files (placed in different folders?) or a single `build.gradle` which builds APK for Android and JAR for JavaFX

The question is: how to achieve this?

Comment: Are you using [gluon](https://gluonhq.com/developers/)? If so, they have a support page and specific tags they use on StackOverflow.  If you are not, then ignore this comment.

Comment: [openjfx](https://github.com/openjdk/jfx) is built for many platforms and uses gradle as its primary build system. So perhaps, its build source may provide some suggestions on how to achieve what you want, though I guess it is likely quite complicated and doing things a bit different from your requirements.

Comment: @jewelsea, sure I'm using openjfx, but it doesn't solve my problem. I have to use 2 different build files for Android and openjfx separate.

Comment: I meant look at the build file in the openjfx repository I linked.  It builds many modules and systems for lots of different platforms from, largely, a single build.gradle, my suggestion was to perhaps study that. It might help you answer your questions of "either 2 different build.gradle files or single build.gradle" (openjfx uses mainly a single file but can use others) and "how to achieve this?" (openjfx build does both) But as I said, it is likely *way* more complicated than what you need and there is almost certainly an easier way (I don't know enough about gradle to assist directly).

Comment: Okay, I caught your idea, looks like it could be useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using gradles suggested project structure and have both code bases and the java core be a separate subproject. The project JavaFx and Android can both depend on the java project. Then you can either build just one of them or both. Gradle will automatically rebuild the java base as well, when needed.

See [Gradle project structure](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/organizing_gradle_projects.html#always_define_a_settings_file)

Comment: Yes, you're right. Solution was simple: divide everything to 3 subprojects: common - java library, fx - includes common and android includes the same common subproject.